# Where can I find which versions of groovy work with versions of grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

Searching around Google I can't find any official compatibility matrix of any sort.  For example, I'd like to know if I can safely use Grails 2.3.8 on Groovy 2.3.

Comment: This question will be more relevant if https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8339 is ever implemented.  Until then, it is a non-issue because we don't support plugging in your own version anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always use whatever version of Groovy is included with Grails. If you look inside the directory where Grails is installed you can discover which version of Groovy this is. Here's an example from my system:

```
grails/2.3.8/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars$ ls
groovy-all-2.1.9-javadoc.jar groovy-all-2.1.9-sources.jar groovy-all-2.1.9.jar
```

So Groovy 2.1.9 is the version bundled with Grails 2.3.8. This is the only version of Groovy that is recommended for this Grails version.

Comment: Is the colored term `all` used as a kind of asterisk here? In my grails installation, there is: groovy  groovy-ant  groovy-groovydoc  groovy-jmx  groovy-json  groovy-templates  groovy-xml .

Comment: @philburns No, that's just the Stackoverflow syntax highlighter guessing how to format this text as code. I think the `groovy-all` JAR may have been dropped from later versions of Groovy in favour of multiple smaller JARs